# Please any suggestion to do this example bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

[Boostrap responsive exemple simple page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2fBO.png)

Please any code suggestion to do this example bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), particularly the [Mix and Match](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match) section.

You can do something like:

- header on the first row
- 1,2,3 elements on the second row
- and finally the 2 footers on the third row

Make sure you use breakpoints (*sm* and *xs*) as suggested in the image.

If you must use react-bootstrap, then [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#responsive-grids) you can find the equivalent documentation

Comment: Thank you sir , please if you can make for me this code

Comment: I absolutely cannot.